# PostgreSQL - INNER JOIN vs WHERE, which one will perform better?

Tags: postgresql, join, where-clause, database-performance

I've just made a quick search through the web but couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for.

How much efficient an **INNER JOIN** is comparing to a regular **WHERE** statement?

I have a couple of queries in PostgreSQL that need to use some tables (say four or five) "linked" together by key/foreign key conditions. To implement those queries I'm using the **WHERE** clause to join all the required tables.

I wonder if any performance gains will bd achieved if I re-write those queries with the **INNER JOIN** clause (instead of a WHERE clause).

Comment: Just compare the query plans: they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you mean to say is difference between the below queries

```
select a.col1,b.col2 from table1 a, table2 b where a.id = b.id;
```

Against

```
select a.col1,b.col2 from table1 a
join table2 b on a.id = b.id;
```

To my knowledge, both are doing a `INNER JOIN`; it's just that the above one is a old style, hard to read, error prone implicit join syntax and the below one is recommended explicit join syntax.

So, I don't see any performance gain/loss here; since either way they are performing the same thing.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This example explains well the point of my question. I just want to make sure that the optimizer will convert those both query implementations to the same query plan, which will make both implementations perform the same.

Comment: Yes since inherently they both are same.

Comment: You can use `explain analyze` to get the execution plan with both queries (the one joining tables in the `where` and the other one joining tables with `join` syntax) and compare both plans: they will be the same, with same operations and records filtered.